# Gdx.input.getY is flipped

Tags: java, libgdx

I have an issue in LibGDX where when i call upon Gdx.input.getY(), it selects a pixel that's on the other side of the application relative to the center of the screen.

[image: screenshot]

```
public class Main extends ApplicationAdapter {
private SpriteBatch batch;
private Texture img;
private OrthographicCamera camera;
int xPos;
int yPos;
private Vector3 tp = new Vector3();
BitmapFont font;

@Override
public void create () {
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    img = new Texture("crosshair.png");
    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.setToOrtho(false, 1280, 720);
    font = new BitmapFont();

}

@Override
public void render () {
    yPos = Gdx.input.getY();
    xPos = Gdx.input.getX();
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    camera.unproject(tp.set(xPos, yPos, 0));
    batch.begin();
    font.draw(batch,xPos + " , " + yPos, Gdx.input.getX() - 25, Gdx.input.getY() - 5);
    batch.draw(img, xPos, yPos);
    batch.end();
}

@Override
public void dispose () {
    batch.dispose();
    img.dispose();
}
```

Comment: So subtract that value from the total height.

Comment: top left is 0,0 that's just how OpenGL works.

Comment: Both answers are only right so long as the window and camera don't change size. The correct way to do this is to use camera.unproject() to convert screen coordinates to world coordinates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subtracting the viewport height with the touch location won't work, because that would be subtracting world coordinates with touch coordinates. (and even for a pixel perfect projection it would be `height - 1 - y`). Instead use the unproject method to convert touch coordinates to world coordinates.

There are two problems with your code:

- You are never setting the batch projection matrix.
- Even though you are using the `unproject` method, you are never using its result.

So instead use the following:

```
@Override
public void render () {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    batch.begin();
    camera.unproject(tp.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0));
    font.draw(batch,tp.x+ " , " + tp.y, tp.x - 25, tp.y - 5);
    batch.draw(img, tp.x, tp.y);
    batch.end();
}
```

I would suggest to read the following pages, which describe this and the reasoning behind it in detail:

- https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Coordinate-systems
- https://xoppa.github.io/blog/pixels/
- https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports

Answer (score 0):

It's better to try this

```
yPos = camera.viewportHeight - Gdx.input.getY();
```